# nginx ошибка 502 Bad gateway

Tags: yii, php-fpm

Проект на Yii, но при переходе по одному из пунктов меню стал выдавать 502 ошибку bad gateway. Строка лога:

```
2018/02/06 17:28:04 [error] 308#308: *50489886 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: мой_ип, server: admin.мой_сайт, request: "GET /client/report/total HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.мой_сайт", referrer: "http://admin.мой_сайт/device"
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: при запросе бекенд возвращает ошибку (или бекенд не запущен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё просто: перезагрузил сервис и заработало:

```
/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

nginx не дождался ответа от скрипта (если там fcgi) или от Apache, если настроено через него.
Т.е. что-то тормозит у вас в коде

Comment: в таком случае был бы 504 статус